# React Grommet, reload/refresh of Table is not working once any one column sort is done

Tags: reactjs, sorting, reload, grommet

Data table has 4 columns, when I sort based on one of column and then reload, the table should have the latest record first( which is having highest ID value)

function refresh(){
getData(); // which will give me 15 records
setPage(1)  // Go to page1
setCount(10) // Show only 10 records in page 1
}